# Asynchronous broadcast client in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, client-server

any help/feedback would be appreciated. I'm developing a broadcast client receiver such that it receives data coming from the server. the client sends and receives data ASYNCHRONOUSLY. in other words i make use of methods such as socket.BeginReceiveFrom() and socket.BeginSendTo()
however, i would like to somehow get the IP ADDRESS of the server, but when i use the method RemoteEndPoint() to get the IP address of the server i get errors. Part of the code is shown below.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    byteData = msgToSend.ToByte();

    clientSocket.BeginSendTo(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, epServer, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), null);

    byteData = new byte[1024];
    //Start listening to the data asynchronously
    clientSocket.BeginReceiveFrom (byteData,0, byteData.Length,SocketFlags.None,ref epServer,new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),null);
}

private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar) {            
    try {                
        clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
        byteData = new byte[1024];

        // HERE MY CODE TO FIND THE IP ADDRESS OF THE SERVER
        IPEndPoint ip = (IPEndPoint)epServer.RemoteEndPoint;
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ip.Address));

        //Start listening to receive more data from the user
        clientSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, byteData.Length,             SocketFlags.None, ref epServer,new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
    } catch (ObjectDisposedException) { 

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "SGSclient: " + strName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is an extension of your previous question:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842443/asynchronous-client-broadcast-receiver/7853129#7853129  The answer I provided there will should allow you to get the server's IP

Comment: Thx robowahoo, i just saw my error in the code you show in the link. instead of EndReceived() method, i used EndReceiveFrom() which returns the end point.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error since your are mixing TCP and UDP.

`EndReceive` is used for connection based protocols. As are the `RemoteEndPoint` property.

You should invoke [EndReceiveFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.endreceivefrom.aspx) which also returns the remote end point